# tesseract silent installation through powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, tesseract

I am trying to install Tesseract-OCR application on a windows server through powershell but I cannot find any switches for silent install. Anyone done this before or know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add /S argument to silently install it.
Command will be like this:

```
tesseract.exe /S
```